# Parameterized pytest fixture that runs PySpark in local and Yarn mode

Tags: python, pyspark, pytest

I have what I assume is a fairly common use case. I have functions that I've written for PySpark that I'd like to test in local and Yarn mode. pytest fixtures work great for this -- you can simply write a parameterized fixture that runs over both modes.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session",
                params=[pytest.mark.spark_local('local'),
                        pytest.mark.spark_yarn('yarn')])
def spark_context(request):
    if request.param == 'local':
        conf = (SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .setAppName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing")
                )
    elif request.param == 'yarn':
        conf = (SparkConf()
                .setMaster("yarn-client")
                .setAppName("pytest-pyspark-yarn-testing")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
                .set("spark.executor.instances", 2)
                )
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: sc.stop())

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    return sc
```

The problem is that you cannot launch multiple Spark contexts at the same time. If you try to run this fixture, you'll get an exception. Any ideas how to fix this? Maybe the scope?

An alternative hack I use is to mark the parameterization and run them separately:

```
py.test -m spark_local
...
py.test -m spark_yarn
...
```

Has anyone run into this or have any thoughts on how to accomplish this with a single call to `py.test`?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is [an issue](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/8911) with creating `SparkContext`s in both local and then yarn mode. The following code seems to work for me to run tests in both yarn and local mode. Just a simple switch in the order was all it took!

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session",
                params=[pytest.mark.spark_yarn('yarn'),
                        pytest.mark.spark_local('local')])
def spark_context(request):
    if request.param == 'local':
        conf = (SparkConf()
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .setAppName("pytest-pyspark-local-testing")
                )
    elif request.param == 'yarn':
        conf = (SparkConf()
                .setMaster("yarn-client")
                .setAppName("pytest-pyspark-yarn-testing")
                .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
                .set("spark.executor.instances", 2)
                )
    request.addfinalizer(lambda: sc.stop())

    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    return sc
```